# NextJS too many redis clients - How to handle with one client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, redis

### Introduction

Hey :)

I created a next app for a discord web-dashboard and use redis as my database.

---

### The main Problem

Every time I make an axios request to one of my docs in the api folder, where a redis client is needed, a new redis client connects to my database.

---

### What did I try already?

I tried it with .quit() after my requests and I tried to add redis into the SessionProvider. But there I had the problem, that the redis property was undefined on the browsers console/clientsided. On my IDE console/serversided, it wasn't undefined.

I wanted to paste the redis property through the SessionProvider but I got the error "Module not found: dns" every time when I hadn't previously queried whether typeof window was undefined when creating the redis client.

---

### My questions

1. Why does this not work with .quit()?
2. Is there a better/easier way to prevent connecting many redis clients to my db?
3. How do you handle this?

---

Thanks for answers and sorry when I messed up things, I am new in next and I wanna learn :)

---

### Code

**My _app.js:**

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import '@/styles/custom.css'

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

**My connection.js:**

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const { REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_PASSWORD } = serverRuntimeConfig;

let redis = null;

if (!redis) {
    const Redis = require('ioredis');
    redis = new Redis({
        host: REDIS_HOST,
        port: REDIS_PORT,
        password: REDIS_PASSWORD
    });
}

export default redis
```

**addItemToBlacklist.js from API Folder:**

```
import client from '../../database/connection'


const addToBlacklist = async (nick) => {
  client.rpush(['blacklist', nick]).then(() => {
    client.quit();
  });
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.addnick)
  const nick = req.query.addnick;
  await addToBlacklist(nick);
  res.status(200).json({ status: "OK" });
}
```

**The Axios request from my BlacklistCard.js:**

```
const addNick = (props) => {
        axios.post("/api/addItemToBlacklist?addnick=" + props)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently calling the quit() method on every request, which causes your Redis client to disconnect from the server. Then, when a new request comes in, a new instance of the Redis client is created. To solve this issue, you should remove the `quit()` method to prevent disconnection from the Redis server on every request.

However, if you still want to connect and disconnect to the Redis server on every request, you should create a new connection within the request instead of at the module level.

Here is an example code:

```js
const addToBlacklist = async (nick) => {
  const redis = new Redis({
    host: REDIS_HOST,
    port: REDIS_PORT,
    password: REDIS_PASSWORD
  });

  await redis.rpush('blacklist', nick);
  redis.quit();
};
```